# onload event is not working in body tag by JavaScript in master page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to show the date and time at `onload` event of the body tag in master page using JavaScript in asp.net. But it is not working, the JavaScript method is not fired.

Here is my code

```
<script>

    function display_c() {
        var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
        mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
    }

    function display_ct() {
        alert();
        var strcount
        var x = new Date()
        document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
        tt = display_c();
    }

</script>

<body onload="display_ct()">
  <div style="width:300px; float:left;">
       <span id='ct'></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now, for my thinking this code is perfect but then also alert is not being shown, as per I show in `display_ct()` JavaScript function.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: there is no error. I am telling that onload event is not working.

Comment: Literally there seems to be no error, the code seems to work as expected in JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j9kez4dm/

Comment: @Matus thats why I describe that this code is not working in master page of asp.net

Comment: Try it with onload="javascript:display_ct()"

Comment: @MarcusH it also not working